# замена mouseenter/mouseleave на click при маленьком разрешении экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли как-то реализовать такое многоуровневое меню, чтобы при разрешении 768px управление переходило на клики вместо наведения?

```
https://codepen.io/alexei-danilovich/pen/KBdjbp
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Подпункт меню 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Подпункт меню 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Подпункт меню 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.sub-menu {
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
opacity: 0; 
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

JS

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');

for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", showSub, false);
  el[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", hideSub, false);
}

function showSub(e) {
    if(this.children.length>1) {
       this.children[1].style.height = "auto";
       this.children[1].style.overflow = "visible";
       this.children[1].style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}

function hideSub(e) {
    if(this.children.length>1) {
      this.children[1].style.height = "0px";
      this.children[1].style.overflow = "hidden";
      this.children[1].style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то реализовать такое многоуровневое меню, чтобы при разрешении 768px управление переходило на клики вместо наведения?

Вот так можно:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
// Дефолтная загрузка
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
  setEvent(el);
} else {
  remEvent(el);
  setEvent(el, "dblclick", "click");
}
// Проверка если окно поменяло размер
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {

  console.log('Resized', this.innerWidth, this.innerHeight);
  if (this.innerWidth <= 768) { // Your size
    // удаляет события
    remEvent(el);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // меняет события
    setEvent(el, "dblclick", "click");
  } else {
    setEvent(el);
  }
})

//----------------------------------------------------------------

function setEvent(elem, e1 = "mouseenter", e2 = "mouseleave", flg = false) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener(e1, showSub, flg);
    elem[i].addEventListener(e2, hideSub, flg);
  }
}

function remEvent(elem, e1 = "mouseenter", e2 = "mouseleave", ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    // Remove 
    elem[i].removeEventListener(e1, showSub);
    elem[i].removeEventListener(e2, hideSub);

  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

function showSub(e) {
  if (this.children.length > 1) {
    this.children[1].style.height = "auto";
    this.children[1].style.overflow = "visible";
    this.children[1].style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function hideSub(e) {
  if (this.children.length > 1) {
    this.children[1].style.height = "0px";
    this.children[1].style.overflow = "hidden";
    this.children[1].style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Подпункт меню 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Подпункт меню 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Подпункт меню 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```